# Precision '39' required to send all values in column 'Cost' exceeds the maximum supported precision '38'. The values must all fit in a single precisi

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, datatable, precision

I've found one similar post but with no actual solution. Can anyone help me on this?

I have a .Net DataTable with a column of type Decimal. The datatable is passed to a SQL Server stored procedure for processing as table value parameter on a SQLClient.SQLCommand. The parameter type is a Table Type where the column is type money

I have used this technique to process billions of rows over many years.

Today however, with this simple data, I am getting the error above. What is strange is that if I process them individually or even in small batches, they all work but not as a whole?
I did try changing the Table Type to float and decimal(26,6) but got the same error

123456789123.45
123456789123.124
123456789123.123
2735.132217
2598.375606
2598.375606
431.8629817
434.0222966
434.0222966
1583.497599
1747.7364
1747.7364
1936.483346
1936.483346
58.09450039
4841.208366
174.2835012
174.2835012
193.6483346
19.36483346
29.04725019
38.72966692

Any help would be appreciated as my system is down.

Comment: The values all comfortably fit in decimal(26,6), so maybe that's not the problem; what is the SP doing with the values? Could it be that the values are being summed somewhere and the *total* of *all* values does not fit in 26,6?

Comment: You don't show any code. I am guessing the problem is in the stored procedure - it is probably calculating a value for column 'Cost'.  You might have to do some explicit casting to avoid the implicit which is coming up with a not allowed precision.  Try running the same data through stored procedure from SSMS to see if the problem persists there and if so post the procedure code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I dont think it gets to the procedure It fails on SqlCommand.ExecuteCommand. The sproc the other end simply does this SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [ExtractRepository].dbo.[BudgetItemCostDetal]
SELECT
  *
INTO
  [ExtractRepository].dbo.[BudgetItemCostDetail]
FROM
  @BudgetItemCostDetail
And to repeat, it only fails when all those values are present.

Comment: Must be more to the story; [I can't reproduce](https://dbfiddle.uk/j1jPIfxb).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.